# IPython Kernel Non-Responsive: Running a Django development server from an IPython Notebook

Tags: django, command-line, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run this line of code in an IPython Notebook:

```
!manage.py runserver
```

It executes `manage.py runserver` on the command line and then starts the Django development server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and allows me to debug / develop my Django project.

The problem is that when I execute this in the notebook the notebook hangs because the Django server is constantly reloading / does not pass control back.

Is there any way to pass an interrupt like `Control+C` to the command line  or gain control over the IPython kernel so that I can continue along with my project in the notebook?

Comment: try the common shell syntax for "run-in-the-background" using `!manage.py runserver &` ? Good luck.

Comment: thanks! Great idea but I get the error: 
`OSError: Background processes not supported.`

Comment: have you tried putting the command with & in a script and calling the script from the notebook cell?

Comment: @Mono did you see @shelter's comment above? I ran `!manage.py runserver &` and  got this error from IPython: `OSError: Background processes not supported.`

Comment: yes, I saw this, but my suggestion is put the whole command (with & too) into a shell script and call that script without &. THis & is causing ipython to see it is a background process.

Comment: should something like : `start cmd.exe /c "manage.py runserver &" ` in  a bat file do it? if so I haven't had any success.

Comment: oh, you're running under windows. `&` won't help, unless you install Cygwin or another Unix-like environment. That may or may not be an easy task. I would try and find the support site for the developers of iPython. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up an issue on IPython dev's  github.  Minrk found this solution:

```
import subprocess
server = subprocess.Popen(["python", "manage.py", "runserver"])
```

it allows me to view the dev server and continue to develop it in the IPython Notebook. sweet!